# I am getting this error TS2563: The containing function or module body is too large for control flow analysis. after merging the branches

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two ng-template in the HTML page out of one is getting this error. in the ng-template we have two buttons named as "OK" and "CANCLE". I am not sure whether it is because linting issue or any condition is getting triggered at DOM level.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBtng.png)

Comment: Without code, we cannot solve enything. Also, the error is very clear on what is the issue.

Comment: The issue is resolved. we were getting this error  because of *ngIf condition. It was breaking at DOM loading.

Comment: Adding some code with explanation would be cool if someone stumbled into this too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.